# Can this be shortened?

Tags: c#

This code looks into 6 array elements and check to see if they are equal to or less than zero, the first thing is that I don't like about it is it's to long, and secondly it gives me 6 winner screen because of the 6 array elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray().Length; i++)
{
    if (parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[0].getMonHealth() <= 0 
      && parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[1].getMonHealth() <= 0 
      && parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[2].getMonHealth() <= 0 
      && parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[3].getMonHealth() <= 0 
      && parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[4].getMonHealth() <= 0 
      && parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[5].getMonHealth() <= 0)
    {
        Winner winners = new Winner();
        winners.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: First things first: write idiomatic C# by using properties and pascal casing. Then, you can simplify this easily with LINQ.

Comment: Clue: Any time use see repeating identical expressions like `parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()` you can at least store the value in a local variable and reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can do the following using the [.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method in Linq

```
bool anyLessThanZero = 
    parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()
    .Any(monster => monster.getMonHealth() <= 0);
```

Comment: Note that original code was `.Take(6).All(monster => monster.getMonHealth() <= 0)` which is somewhat opposite of `Any`... But does it really matter if it is what OP wants?

Comment: I went off the text in the question rather than the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign `parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()` to a variable and replace `parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()` with the variable instead in your code so you don't have to type it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost doesn't look like C#...

Compare it to this:

```
// assume CurrentPlayer is a property that returns Players[Turn]
var currentPlayer = parent.Game.CurrentPlayer;

if (currentPlayer.Monsters.All(monster => monster.Health <= 0))
{
    var winner = new Winner();
    winner.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

You should use properties instead of getter methods. Also, the C# convention is that locals are camelCased, and types/properties/methods are PascalCased.